# CLLocation Region Monitoring behaves differently in iOS 5.1 and iOS 6

Tags: ios5, ios6, core-location, cllocationmanager

**UPDATE: I am looking for a workaround to this problem in iOS5.1. Currently, I have evidence that this issue in fact is known. However, I think it is related to an updated xcode rather than iOS5.1 actually region monitoring not working.**

The simple code below behaves differently between iOS5 and iOS6. It works as expected in iOS6.

But in iOS5, the didEnterRegion callback is only triggered the first time the region is entered. If you exit the region, then re-enter the region, it will not be triggered. If you close and restart the app, entering the region will not trigger the callback.

The difference in behavior was seen on the iOS5 and iOS6 simulators. The broken iOS5 behavior was seen on an iPhone 4S with iOS5. Xcode 4.6 was used. CoreLocation framework was added properly, and locMan is a property of the AppDelegate. A clean new project was created for this test.

Can someone please find a workaround to this problem? The fix needs to use region monitoring, not active location updating.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocationManager *locMan;

@end


// AppDelegate implementation file

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    /// LocationManager
    self.locMan = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locMan.delegate = self;

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(40.0, 40.0);
    CLLocationDistance distance = 100.0;
    CLRegion *region = [[CLRegion alloc] initCircularRegionWithCenter:coordinates radius:distance identifier:@"hello"];
    [self.locMan startMonitoringForRegion:region];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
    NSLog(@"didEnterRegion");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After leaving this question open for a week, I feel that I've enough evidence that region monitoring is broken in iOS5.1. Time to close out the question.